# How to display over state of a SimpleButton at up state

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have a menu with button objects in As3. I want to display the page where user is and for this I must show buttons' over state (which is mc) when flash loads. I'm sending the page parameter to flash. I just need to play the movie clip inside the specific button.

Looking for something like:

```
btn1.m1.gotoAndPlay(1); or btn1.m1.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Adobe's documentation helped to solve the problem. It toked one day to figure it out but finally I found the appropriate code. It's not maybe the best but it does the trick.:

```
btn1.upState = btn1.overState;
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
btn1.getChildByName("m1").play();
```

EDIT:
...oh, sorry I thought you where talking about a generic button but you are using SimpleButton class:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html

the class by default should play any movieClips you put in there, but accessing it's childs it's a different story, take a look into this:
http://www.xtyler.com/code/254

Comment: "Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton."

Comment: I want to show over state when user opens a specific page. That is why I need this. I want to over button without any action.